# In memory Sqlite with Next.js -- is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm demoing a project and I need access to a database in my local environment. I don't want to connect over the internet to an internet-based provider.

To simulate this, however, I want to use sqlite. I installed sequelize, an ORM for sqlite and want to load a new instance of a database each time Next.js loads and populate it with some data (see below).

How would I run this code -- the populateUsers() function below?

I thought I could use getServerSideProps() in _app.js, but discovered recently this isn't possible. I only need to run this function once, when the app loads, and then of course on each successive re-load as it's an in-memory database.

```
import { Sequelize, QueryTypes } from "sequelize";

const sequelize = new Sequelize("sqlite::memory:");

export const isConnOk = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
};

export const execute = async (sql: string) => {
  const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(sql);

  return [results, metadata];
};

export const query = async (sql: string) => {
  const results = await sequelize.query(sql, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });

  return results;
};

export const populateUsers = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("START: populating database");

    await execute(
      "create table users ( id integer, name varchar(50), username varchar(50), city_of_birth varchar(50) );"
    );

    await execute(
      "insert into users values ( '1', 'gary', 'garym', 'seattle' );"
    );

    await execute(
      "insert into users values ( '2', 'christine', 'chris', 'miami' );"
    );

    console.log("COMPLETE: database populated");
  } catch {
    console.log("FAILURE: did not populate database");
  }
};
```

Comment: If willing to switch to Prisma, it is possible and easy to do in [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database)

Comment: Isn't prisma internet based?

Comment: You can use a file, see [Prisma's sqlite example](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sqlite#example)

Comment: How would I do this in Prisma? Is Prisma a better alternative than sequelize?

Comment: I'm searching if I can use Prisma in memory.

Comment: See the links I provided in my earlier comments, they both provide examples. I have not personally used sequelize so cannot give an opinion, but I have used Prisma and like it a lot. You cannot use an in memory database with Prisma ([see issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/732)), but you can use a file which in a lot of cases should be a viable alternative.